# Facebook loading albums in uitableview but not opening in next collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to access facebook albums and i implemented it in my app but when i ran it. it shows all the albums but not showing pictures in those albums when i select a album. here is my code 
NOTE: there is a xib for albumsviewcontroller but no xib for FacebookPhotoViewController so do i need to create one?

here is cellforraw method from albumsviewcontroller

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RTFacebookAlbumCell* cell = (RTFacebookAlbumCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RTFacebookAlbumCell" owner:self options:nil][0];
    }
    cell.albumName.text = _datasource[indexPath.row][@"name"];
    for (NSDictionary* dict in _albumCoverArray) {
        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"index"] intValue] == indexPath.row) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
                NSData* imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[dict objectForKey:@"URL"]];
                UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    cell.albumLogo.image = img;
                });
            });
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FacebookPhotoViewController* vc = [[FacebookPhotoViewController alloc] init];
    vc.albumId = [[_datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
    vc.delegate = _delegate;
    vc.title = [[_datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

and here is FacebookPhotoViewController

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            _datasource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            [self sendRequest];

            UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
            self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:flow];
            self.collectionView.delegate = self;
            self.collectionView.dataSource = self;

            [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
            [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

            [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
    -(void)sendRequest {
NSString* graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos?fields=created_time,name,picture&type=tagged", _albumId];    

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:graphPath parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            NSDictionary* resultDict = (NSDictionary*)result;

            NSDictionary* dict  = [resultDict objectForKey:@"photos"];
            NSArray* array = [dict objectForKey:@"data"];
            for (NSDictionary* innerDict in array) {
                NSString* source = [innerDict objectForKey:@"source"];
                [_datasource addObject:source];
            }
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"Result is: %@",resultDict); **//Getting all pictures created date and id here**
        }];
    }

    -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return _datasource.count;
    }

    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"cell";
        UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
        imageView.tag = 100;
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            NSData* imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_datasource[indexPath.row]]];
            UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [imageView setImage:img];
            });
        });

        return cell;
    }

    -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (_delegate) {
            UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            UIImageView* imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
            [_delegate faceBookViewController:self didSelectPhoto:imageView.image];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
```

when i open FacebookPhotoViewController here is nothing just album name in navigation title that is it. please help

here is output
[image]

Comment: you get the`_albumId` , if Yes whst the result u get here `resultDict`

Comment: i nslog resultdict but there is no output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
NSString* graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@?fields=photos", _albumId];
```

into and try once

```
NSString* graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos", _albumId];
```

**updated**

```
 NSString* graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos?fields=created_time,name,picture&type=tagged", _albumId];
```

**updated -2**

change this line

```
  NSString* source = [innerDict objectForKey:@"source"];
```

to

```
   NSString* source = [innerDict objectForKey:@"picture"];
```

**detailed answer**

```
      NSDictionary* resultDict = (NSDictionary*)result;
       NSArray* array = [resultDict objectForKey:@"data"];
 for (NSDictionary* innerDict in array) {
            NSString* source = [innerDict objectForKey:@"picture"]; 
            [_datasource addObject:source];
        }

   if (_datasource.count >0)
   {
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
   }
```

Comment: great now i am getting output in resultDict with all the images ids but not showing!

Comment: @VixHunk - happy to hear , I did not worked with this concept in before, ok can you update the question with `resultDict`

Comment: tried now gettin all the details including photo but not showing anything!!

Comment: @VixHunk - really happy can you show the output of result

Comment: what the output you get in here `_datasource` or `dict`

Comment: "created_time" = "2014-03-02T19:26:58+0000";
            id = 10152065856123051;
            name = ":D";
            picture = "https://fbcdn-photos-d-a.akmaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/1962885_10152023051_404011969_n.jpg?oh=13507af99e5ae08c672649cb05e&oe=584B8AA7&__gda__=1482112031_9d88bc2f3d9d45adb27a6b3d84e";

Comment: here it is its the output of dict

Comment: @VixHunk - show in JSOn format properly it is easy to resolve

Comment: @VixHunk - check the `detailed answer` answer bro

Comment: sorry bro again same output n no images :(

Comment: something mistake , can you print `_datasource`

Comment: i nslog it and there is nothing in out just empty nslog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120790/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-vix-hunk).